# Clarification on options jargon regarding spreads

Tags: options, option-strategies, spreads

Is it true that a bull put spread is the same as a credit put spread. Because if I am bullish, I wont be buying the put spread, I will be selling it, so it has got to be a credit spread.

Similarly , is a bear put spread the same as a put debit spread?

Is a bull call spread the same as a call debit spread and is a bear call spread the same as a call credit spread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It seems to me you got it right.

On my site, [Stock Options Cafe](http://stockoptionscafe.com/), my last post was an illustration of a bullish call spread. In this case, I bought a 50 call, and sold the 60 call. This is a debit order as I was paying money, not collecting a new premium.

[image]